# Which model is better while using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-annotation

What is the best approach for managing State for Views in RiverPod?
I want to have all the screen states (list data, order, page, search filter, etc.) in State.

A. Use AsyncNotifier for @freezed State classes

- It is necessary to prepare multiple Providers because they are all AsyncData and you cannot select for specific fields.
- The method of writing Provider for data that is not AsyncData is not good.

B. Use Notifiers for @freezed State classes

- It is necessary to perform initialization processing in Notifier's build method.

C. Use AsyncNotifier and Notifier without creating a State class

- It becomes difficult to understand the feeling of managing the state because the Notifier is disjointed.
- It has the least amount of code and is simple.

Below is a code sample.

View

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:openapi/openapi.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/providers/users/list1.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_app/providers/users/list2.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_app/providers/users/list3.dart';

class UsersListPage extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const UsersListPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // list1, list3
    final AsyncValue<List<ModelUser>> users = ref.watch(usersProvider);
    final String orderBy = ref.watch(orderByProvider);
    // list2
    // final AsyncValue<List<ModelUser>> users = ref.watch(usersListPageNotifierProvider.select((value) => value.users));
    // final String orderBy = ref.watch(usersListPageNotifierProvider.select((value) => value.orderBy));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("TEST"),
      ),
      body: users.when(
        data: (users) {
          print('rendering!!!');
          return ListView(
            children: users.map((user) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.map),
                title: Text('${user.lastName ?? ""} ${user.firstName ?? ""}'),
                onTap: () {
                  context.go('/users/${user.id}');
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
        error: (err, stack) {
          print('error!!!');
          return Text('Error: $err');
        },
        loading: () {
          print('loading!!!');
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // list1, list2
          ref.read(usersListPageNotifierProvider.notifier).setOrderBy("id desc");
          // list3
          // ref.read(orderByProvider.notifier).set("id desc");
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.sort),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A.　list1.dart

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:openapi/openapi.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/general_provider.dart';

part 'list1.g.dart';

part 'list1.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class UsersListPageState with _$UsersListPageState {
  const factory UsersListPageState({
    @Default([]) List<ModelUser> users,
    @Default("id") String orderBy,
    @Default("") String filter,
  }) = _UsersListPageState;
}

@riverpod
class UsersListPageNotifier extends _$UsersListPageNotifier {
  Future<List<ModelUser>> _fetchUsers() async {
    final cancelToken = CancelToken();
    ref.onDispose(() => cancelToken.cancel());
    final String orderBy = state.value?.orderBy ?? "id";
    final users = await ref
        .read(openApiProvider)
        .getUserApi()
        .searchUser(orderBy: orderBy, cancelToken: cancelToken)
        .then((res) => res.data!.users!.toList());
    return users;
  }

  @override
  Future<UsersListPageState> build() async {
    return const UsersListPageState().copyWith(users: await _fetchUsers());
  }

  setOrderBy(String orderBy) {
    final previousState = state.valueOrNull;
    if (previousState == null) {
      return;
    }
    state = AsyncValue.data(previousState.copyWith(orderBy: orderBy));
    refresh();
  }

  setFilter(String filter) {
    final previousState = state.valueOrNull;
    if (previousState == null) {
      return;
    }
    state = AsyncValue.data(previousState.copyWith(filter: filter));
    refresh();
  }

  refresh() async {
    final previousState = state.valueOrNull;
    if (previousState == null) {
      return;
    }
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      final users = await _fetchUsers();
      return previousState.copyWith(users: users);
    });
  }
}

@riverpod
Future<List<ModelUser>> users(UsersRef ref) {
  return ref.watch(
      usersListPageNotifierProvider.selectAsync((data) => data.users)
  );
}

@riverpod
String orderBy(OrderByRef ref) {
  return ref.watch(
      usersListPageNotifierProvider.select((data) => data.value?.orderBy ?? "")
  );
}
```

B. list2.dart

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:openapi/openapi.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/general_provider.dart';

part 'list2.g.dart';

part 'list2.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class UsersListPageState with _$UsersListPageState {
  const factory UsersListPageState({
    @Default(AsyncValue.loading()) AsyncValue<List<ModelUser>> users,
    @Default("id") String orderBy,
    @Default("") String filter,
  }) = _UsersListPageState;
}

@riverpod
class UsersListPageNotifier extends _$UsersListPageNotifier {
  Future<List<ModelUser>> _fetchUsers() async {
    final cancelToken = CancelToken();
    ref.onDispose(() => cancelToken.cancel());
    final String orderBy = state.orderBy;
    final users = await ref
        .read(openApiProvider)
        .getUserApi()
        .searchUser(orderBy: orderBy, cancelToken: cancelToken)
        .then((res) => res.data!.users!.toList());
    return users;
  }

  @override
  UsersListPageState build() {
    ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
      if (previous != null) {
        return;
      }
      _fetchUsers().then((List<ModelUser> users) {
        state = state.copyWith(users: AsyncValue.data(users));
      });
    });
    return const UsersListPageState();
  }

  setOrderBy(String orderBy) {
    state = state.copyWith(orderBy: orderBy);
    refresh();
  }

  setFilter(String filter) {
    state = state.copyWith(filter: filter);
    refresh();
  }

  refresh() async {
    state = state.copyWith(users: const AsyncValue.loading());
    final users = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      return _fetchUsers();
    });
    state = state.copyWith(users: users);
  }
}
```

C.　list3.dart

```
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:openapi/openapi.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/general_provider.dart';

part 'list3.g.dart';

@riverpod
class Users extends _$Users {
  Future<List<ModelUser>> _fetchUsers() async {
    final cancelToken = CancelToken();
    ref.onDispose(() => cancelToken.cancel());
    final String orderBy = ref.watch(orderByProvider);
    final users = await ref
        .read(openApiProvider)
        .getUserApi()
        .searchUser(orderBy: orderBy, cancelToken: cancelToken)
        .then((res) => res.data!.users!.toList());
    return users;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<ModelUser>> build() async {
    return await _fetchUsers();
  }
}

@riverpod
class OrderBy extends _$OrderBy {
  @override
  String build() => "id";

  void set(String orderBy) {
    state = orderBy;
    ref.invalidate(usersProvider);
  }
}

@riverpod
class Filter extends _$Filter {
  @override
  String build() => "";

  void set(String filter) {
    state = filter;
    ref.invalidate(usersProvider);
  }
}
```

Please let me know the pros and cons of each pattern.
Also, please let me know if there are any improvements in each pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something similar to C with an extra `SortedAndFilteredUsers` provider, the sorting and filtering logic is inside the `SortedAndFilteredUsers` provider instead of the widget and your view consumes this provider directly. With this approach, the code is easier to read and the sorting/filtering logic can be reused across different widgets.

```dart
@riverpod
FutureOr<List<ModelUser>> users(UsersRef ref) {
  final result = ... // fetch users from api
  return result;
}

@riverpod
FutureOr<List<ModelUser>> sortedAndFilteredUsers(SortedAndFilteredUsersRef ref) async {
  final users = await ref.watch(usersProvider.future);
  final orderBy = ref.watch(orderByProvider);
  final filter = ref.watch(filterProvider);

  final result = ... // sort and filter users
  return result;
}

@riverpod
class OrderBy extends _$OrderBy {
  @override
  String build() => 'id';

  void set(String orderBy) {
    state = orderBy;
  }
}

@riverpod
class Filter extends _$Filter {
  @override
  String build() => '';

  void set(String filter) {
    state = filter;
  }
}
```